# Lookup Google Sheets Records & updating as new record

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Good Day,
I have some records in google sheets (responses from an input google form). What I want is to lookup among those records on the sheets via a form a specific record and update it, but instead of replacing the existing record it creates a new one thus maintaining a history for this particular record....

Answer (score 0):

You can create a seperate log tab that (also) saves the respones to a seperated sheet with a script like below. You must install this as a [trigger.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

```
function onFormSubmit(e){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const logSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Log');
  const values = e.values;
  logSheet.getRange(logSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,values.lenght()).setValues(values);

}
```

Comment: Ok thanks for answering, but how do I use a form to populate existing records and have it displayed on the form and then update the said record/form as a new entry? Would there have to be a duplicate of the original form with some script to update and add as a new record...?